# how to get rid of that bar above the tabs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

- What do you call the bar across the top of eclipse IDE with the run and debug buttons on it?
- how can I get rid of it and recover just that much more screen space?

Comment: I find it really helpful to set some views as Fast Views to improve screen real estate in eclipse - get rid of information that you only need at a specific time when you pull it up. In particular, Navigator, Package Explorer, and Console are good candidates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which verison of eclipse?

- Toolbar
- Right click on it - Hide toolbar

And to get it back

- Window Menu / Show Toolbar

Comment: though i'm not sure i want it back ;)

Comment: You may not, but other people reading the answer will be more likely to try it out, if they can see how to get it back.